# How does MtGox Limit sell work?

Tags: mtgox, trading

MtGox has market orders and non-market orders. From what I know, market orders will execute at the current market price whereas the non-market order will execute only at the price that I have set (or a better price).

I have set a non-market order to sell my coins at $183.44/BTC. However, when I look at my logs, the coins were sold for $181.11002.

I've tried to approach MtGox staff but they are simply beating about the bush. Can someone explain why were the coins sold for a price lower than the price set?

Comment: When would fees be deducted from your transaction? Is it perhaps just  traded at correct amount less trading fee?

Comment: @Murch, nope the logs are very clear about that. The fees are only deducted after the trade. And the trade occurs at $181.11002

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually looked at the code but this would be my best guess.

When you place a limit order, your order bid/ask is placed into a queue for that price. When the [inside price](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/insidequote.asp) equals the price of your limit order, it will be executed and removed from the queue.

If what your saying has happened then either you made a mistake in placing the order or mtgox's system has a bug.

Comment: I didn't make a mistake. I think it's a bug with their javascript interface and they are trying to wriggle their way through not compensating me